# Hyperlink not working address automatically updated with extra forward slash

Tags: html, windows, file, hyperlink, visio

I have an HTML document with a hyperlink to a Visio version of the HTML. 
I have been able to successfully access the Visio version, however, now when I click on the hyperlink to access the Visio I am getting an error:

> Windows can't find 'file:///C:/DDL_14.1.1/DDL/HTML/filename.vsd"

Where are these 3 forward slashes prior to the file address coming from? The address link saved in the hyperlink address does not have the 3 forward slashes.

Comment: can you please show your HTML for the hyperlink.

Answer (score 0):

Possible cause: Your web server may not be running. The prefix "file:///" means your browser is trying to access a local file or is assuming so. Have IIS running, and put the file in the folder equivalent of wwwroot or in a virtual directory. Look at the original address of the hyperlink and see whether it points to another web server on the network or on the internet. After you place the file in the wwwroot, in IIS itself you could say 'Browse' and the IIS will serve it with an address that looks like 'localhost' or a local network ip address and port.